# Haproxy Slow Reload in DB Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haproxy

Recently I started using great tool for load balancing - Haproxy.

There is only one disturbing thing that I cannot figure out how to deal with it.
We use haproxy for load balancing mysql traffic. When there is a lot of traffic and many connection it takes ages for haproxy to reload (~ 30 min), with less traffic it doest reload within 1 min.

I do reload with:

```
service haproxy reload
```

Of course if I need to do an urgent change in configuration I expect haproxy to do reload very fast. Killing haproxy instances waiting for disconnection causes to disconnection of msyql connections.

It looks like that I made mistake in settings of haproxy or in settings of application. If you know how to solve this please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the haproxy down for that amount of time while the reload is taking place?  Sounds to me more like it's just waiting for all the connections to die off before actually executing the reload.

Comment: @womble, no it's not down, old instance and the new one are up simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

If you pass `-sf` to HAProxy (probably what the init script does) then the old haproxy will handle connections until they are no longer used. So as long as there is a connection open, haproxy will have two instances until they are all done.

If you app uses connection pooling (keeping connections open for reuse) then it may take a while before these connections close. If you are using connection pooling, then you might want to look for some sort of MaxAge parameter that will cause connections to be closed after they have been open for a certain amount of time (With something like this, the age is checked after transaction is complete, in other words, before the connection is returned to the pool).